# JSON array giving NULL values in word with Accents

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode, iso-8859-1

I have this code to generate json array to send to Android App, but when i get **values with Accents** i get **NULL** values.

this is my code:

```
  <?php 
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);
 include "db_connect.php";


    $userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `mensages` WHERE `iduser` = '$userid' AND `read` = '0' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this PHP function to your code:

```
public static function normalizeChars($s) {
    $replace = array(
        'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'Ae', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ă'=>'A',
        'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'ae', 'å'=>'a', 'ă'=>'a', 'æ'=>'ae',
        'þ'=>'b', 'Þ'=>'B',
        'Ç'=>'C', 'ç'=>'c',
        'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E',
        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 
        'Ğ'=>'G', 'ğ'=>'g',
        'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'İ'=>'I', 'ı'=>'i', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i',
        'Ñ'=>'N',
        'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'Oe', 'Ø'=>'O', 'ö'=>'oe', 'ø'=>'o',
        'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
        'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ş'=>'S', 'ș'=>'s', 'Ș'=>'S', 'ş'=>'s', 'ß'=>'ss',
        'ț'=>'t', 'Ț'=>'T',
        'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'Ue',
        'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ü'=>'ue', 
        'Ý'=>'Y',
        'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'ÿ'=>'y',
        'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z'
    );
    return strtr($s, $replace);
}
```

Then you can change this particular variable `$obResult[$i];` with `normalizeChars($obResult[$i];)`

This will change your letters with accents to nomal letters, the phone can handle.

Comment: public static function or simple function?

Comment: i put it like this : $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = normalizeChars($obResult[$i]);  but still giving me NULL values.